# What is the best way to secure an application with session vars?

Tags: php, security, session

I have an application with an index page, where the user can enter a login and a password. Then they are submitted as POST variables, and if they are both correct, my script creates a session var as follows :

```
$_SESSION['auth'] = $login;
```

and the index page echoes a menu. If they are not, the login window is displayed again, as if the user went on the index page for the first time (with an error message under the required fields).

For now, I verify if the session variable is set :

```
<?php
include 'functions.php'; //this file contains session_start() 
if (!isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
Html stuff with jquery...
</html>
```

Do I have to put all my html stuff in brackets within an else statement, or my page is secured enough ? Even if the user is redirected, the html part is still got by his browser, isn't it ?

I have several PHP pages on my server, and at the beginning of each one I make the same test as above. I also make this verification when the user comes on the index page (if he has already signed in, I don't want him to log-in again).

Assuming my script is safe (all the information provided by the user is checked on server side), what is the best way to work with secure sessions ?

Comment: what do you mean secure sessions? What makes you think they are insure, the only thing you need to do is make sure they are `httponly` and `secure`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 1):

It's great you are thinking about security, but allow me to explain a little on how sessions and session cookies work.

First of all cookies only allow a limited amount of data stored in them, I forget how much but I know it's not limitless.  So how do severs allow you to store all that session data.  What happens is the actual session cookie only stores the session id. On the server there is an actual physical file that has the session data in it.  So when a client connects they send the session id, which in turn tells what file to use.  Therefor, the session is as secure as the severs filesystem and the algorithm used to create the cookie's id.  No actual session data ( besides that id ) leaves the server.

That said there are 2 settings that might help ensure sessions are safe.

These are httponly and secure, you can read more about them here

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly

Now the short of it is, secure means to only transmit the session data ( the session id ) over Https, this only works if you have https setup on your server and website.  Httponly, tells the browser that the cookie should only be sent over http ( or https ) not by client-side scripting.  However as you have no control over what browser the client uses, or  if their computer has been compromised in some way that will tell the browser otherwise ( although I don't know of any exploits that might do that ) you really are just making a suggestion to the client machine.

Now as far as the security of the actual data, any input from anywhere even your own database should always be treated as potentially insecure.  This doesn't mean you have to check it everywhere, mainly that you escape html when outputting to the page, and that you use proper means to prevent sql injection into the database.  As a general rule these should be done at the point of entry.

For example, when outputting content to a page that should not have html, simply use html_entities etc.. when outputting it.  When using data in sql, use prepared statements there.  You see you don't need to check the $_POST data every time you touch it, just check the data before using it for something that could be exploited, such as saving it in the database.

Lets take a small example function ( assume its in a user class )

```
 public function getUser( $id ){
      $sql = "Select * from user where id = $id"
       //execute sql
 }
```

We would never do this using PDO but lets assume this is old school stuff, you filter the data from a login form elsewhere, so when you set this up you assume its always a clean a id, because you filter it at the login form.  Then latter you need a user from the session. Well you have the id there too, so you use it.  Now is that id from the session clean, who knows right. Maybe it's an id from a file, or some other obscure place. Who knows where an Id can come from ( when we make the user class ).  So what we do now-a-days is check that or use a prepared statement "at the point we use" the data, the point of entry.  Then we don't care where the data came from. Because, it is always being cleared at the prepared statement, just before we use it in the database.   That way it is always 100%, no question asked, clean.  We can see it right there where we run the query from.  We don't need to worry if we make a new login form latter.  Maybe you add a pop-up login form somewhere?  Dosn't matter, your sql will always be clean.  Now, I am not saying not to check it at the login form.  Never hurts to be safe, not to mention you might want to validate other things there, email format, uniqueness of a username etc.  But, the critical point, is covered.

Make sense?

To address your comment about not using cookies ( I should have explained this at the beginning ).  By it's very nature the internet is stateless.  What this means is that every page reload is essentially a new connection.  The only way to maintain a login ( or any data across reloads ) is to pass some data between requests.  There is generally only a few ways to do this, they are 
`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILE`, `$_COOKIES`. Notice how they are formatted, that's a hint, they are called super globals.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

By the way we have Netscape to thank for both Cookies and Javascript, both of which IE "borrowed", to me it's sad I don't see Netscape Navigator anymore.  I remember that from the AOL 3.0 days, that was before you could embed images in email.  You old timers know what I am talking about... *Churr.Beep.bong.Cherrrk* (various analog modem noises )... streaming video what's that, it's like 1.5 days to download a song. & Pr@y 2 teh GodZ of de inTerWeBz MomZ do4't g3t a [ call ....  L33t BaBy >:-)~  ^v^

Comment: thanks but I don't use cookies for now, only session variables. But you're right, it is better to have a login process secured with https for them too.

Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I'll try to edit it, thanks

Comment: And how do you think that session is maintained? in a session cookie.  We will do a small experiment, now login to your site you dont use cookies on.  press ctrl+shift+del, to clear the history.  Make sure active logins is checked.  Clear your browsers "cookies".  Now see if you are logged in.

Comment: Wow you added a lot of stuff, thanks for your answer !

Comment: Sure thing, it's the basic foundation of the internet we are talking about.  Once you understand that a request is stateless it all makes sense, promise.

Comment: so far I haven't handled handle the "remember me" stuff and I use private navigation mode ;)

Comment: For remember me, what you want is what I like to call a passport.  Make another separate cookie, that you put a hash code in, and make a separate passport table, to compare it to.  Then you are not exposing a users password, and you can set a lifetime in the table, and clean out old passports that are expired.  The same table can be used to reset a users password by making a login link using the passport code, that is one time use only.  To make a passport you can do `sha1( microtime().$userid.rand(0,10000));` that will give a 40 character string that is always different because of the time.

Comment: I think I get it. The purpose is to expose as less as possible the core of my database with more "clever" requests, with a mechanism that splits the user password into the "real" password, and a random-generated value with a short lifetime, used to access the encrypted password (i.e. to create a new one)

Comment: We'll for the passport thing I mentioned you should not need to use the users password at all, nor do  you need to show their id, `sha1( microtime().$userid.rand(0,10000));` each piece has a specific reason, the time makes it always unique ( the time is always different ), the id is just there to make it more unique to your users, so if 2 are crated at the same instance they are unique because you wont likely make 2 for 1 user.   Both of these could be guessed ( highly unlikely, but not impossible ) so you add a completely random part, to avoid that issue all together.

Comment: It's a bit overkill in insuring it's unique actually, but it's pretty much bullet prof way to get a unique hash.

Comment: great, I'll try this out :)